# I can't see the iptables rules where firewalld enables helpers. Why? Have the helpers been disabled somehow?

Tags: linux, firewalld

> Here is an example of the ftp helper added by enabling the ftp service in the public zone:
>
> ```
> # iptables -t raw -S | grep CT
> -A PRE_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j CT --helper ftp
> ```
>
> https://firewalld.org/2016/10/automatic-helper-assignment

I have not tried to disable any of the default helpers, but running the above command does not show any such rules.  Nor does `sudo iptables-save | grep 21`.  Why?

---

```
# rpm -q firewalld
firewalld-0.5.5-1.fc28.noarch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is an [example] of the ftp helper added by enabling the ftp service in the public zone.

It sounds like the ftp "helper" is only enabled, if you specifically allow the ftp "service" in `firewalld`.  For each helper definition, there should be a matching service definition.

Originally I thought you would only enable a "service" if you were running e.g. an FTP *server*.  FTP *passive* mode, which is preferred nowadays, still requires an extra connection.  The client must connect to the server on a second port, to transfer file data.  The "helper" is needed to detect which port is being used and allow this extra connection.

None of the helpers are marked as `-client` (like the service `dhcpv6-client`).  But as far as I can tell, enabling the FTP service on a *client* will allow it to use the original FTP *active* mode (assuming `firewalld` is the only firewall in the way).  I think this example is not a big security problem, but it could be very confusing :-(.

(Nitpick: FedoraWorkstation will happen to allow FTP active mode anyway, because it allows incoming connections to any port above 1024.  Please do not ask me to explain why).

The second example I looked at was the irc helper, but I cannot understand it.  It looks broken to me.

```
# cat /usr/lib/firewalld/helpers/irc.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<helper module="nf_conntrack_irc" family="ipv4">
  <port protocol="tcp" port="194"/>
</helper>
# cat /usr/lib/firewalld/services/irc.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>IRC</short>
  <description>An IRCd, short for Internet Relay Chat daemon, is server software that implements the IRC protocol.</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="6667"/>
</service>
```